# Create column of new fields from daily fields in SQL Presto

Tags: sql, presto, recursive-query

I would like to calculate the new visitors based on all the visitors that visit each day. Right now the only data I have available is the first 2 columns, so I need to extrapolate the last 2 columns based on the first 2 columns.

| Date | Visitors_Today | New_Visitors | All_Visitors_To_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dec 6 | Allie, Jon | Allie, Jon | Allie, Jon |
| Dec 7 | Allie, Jon, Zach | Zach | Allie, Jon, Zach |
| Dec 8 | Barb, Jon | Barb | Allie, Barb, Jon, Zach |
| Dec 9 | Janet, Zach | Janet | Allie, Barb, Janet, Jon, Zach |

This is what I have so far to create the first and second column

```
WITH visitor_log_response AS (
    SELECT
        CAST(JSON_PARSE(visitor_log) AS MAP<VARCHAR, VARCHAR>) AS visitor_map,
        date
    FROM visitor_log_response_table
),
names_and_dates AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        visitor_name AS visitor_name,
        date
    FROM visitor_log_response 
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(visitor_map) AS u(visitor_name, visitor_age)
),
visitor_names AS (
    SELECT
        date,
        ARRAY_JOIN(
            ARRAY_AGG(
                visitor_name
                ORDER BY
                    visitor_name
            ),
            ','
        ) visitors_today,
    FROM names_and_dates
    GROUP BY
        date
    ORDER BY
        date DESC
)
SELECT
    date,
    visitors_today
FROM visitor_names
```

Which results in this

| Date | Visitors_Today |
| --- | --- |
| Dec 6 | Allie, Jon |
| Dec 7 | Allie, Jon, Zach |
| Dec 8 | Barb, Jon |
| Dec 9 | Janet, Zach |

If the table is normalized using this query

```
SELECT ds, visitors_today_split
FROM previous_table
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(visitors_today),',')) as (visitors_today_split)
```

I would have this output

| Date | Visitors_Today |
| --- | --- |
| Dec 6 | Allie |
| Dec 6 | Jon |
| Dec 7 | Allie |
| Dec 7 | Jon |
| Dec 7 | Zach |
| Dec 8 | Barb |
| Dec 8 | Jon |
| Dec 9 | Janet |
| Dec 9 | Zach |

Comment: Probably this task becomes a snap if the table gets normalized, by transforming the "*Visitors_Today*" into a single-valued field.

Comment: `Dec 6` comes before `Dec 9`, shouldn't Janet and Zach be the first visitors of the 4 days?

Comment: @lemon you are correct, thank you I updated it

Comment: @lemon visitors_today is a single array right now. Can you elaborate on what you mean by normalizing it into a single valued field?  the new columns would need to parse each individual item in the arrays

Comment: Normalization would bring first row to be split into row <'Dec 6', 'Allie'> and row <'Dec 6', 'Jon'>. Following rows as well would have Date duplicates but only one visitor in the second field.

Comment: @lemon I see.  The real data in this query contains thousands of visitors, so ideally i would not expand each name into a new row if possible

Comment: @lemon I normalized the query.  What would be the solution now that it is normalized? I edited post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [window functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html) with array aggregation (remove `ARRAY_JOIN` from `visitor_names` CTE):

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset(date, visitors_today) as (
    values ('Dec 6', array['Allie', 'Jon']),
        ('Dec 7', array['Allie', 'Jon', 'Zach']),
        ('Dec 8', array['Barb', 'Jon']),
        ('Dec 9', array['Janet', 'Zach'])
)

-- query
select date,
    visitors_today,
    array_distinct(visitors_today || prev_visitors) all_visitors_to_date,
    array_except(visitors_today, prev_visitors) new_visitors    
from (
    select *,
           coalesce(
                flatten(array_distinct(array_agg(visitors_today)
                    over (order by date rows between UNBOUNDED PRECEDING and 1 PRECEDING))),
                array[]) as prev_visitors  -- combine all visitors before today into non null array
    from dataset);
```

Output:

| date | visitors_today | all_visitors_to_date | new_visitors |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dec 6 | [Allie, Jon] | [Allie, Jon] | [Allie, Jon] |
| Dec 7 | [Allie, Jon, Zach] | [Allie, Jon, Zach] | [Zach] |
| Dec 8 | [Barb, Jon] | [Barb, Jon, Allie, Zach] | [Barb] |
| Dec 9 | [Janet, Zach] | [Janet, Zach, Allie, Jon, Barb] | [Janet] |

Note that arrays can be not that optimal type in terms of performance and is limited to 10000 elements in Presto/Trino.

Answer (score 2):

You can flatten your arrays and perform new aggregations in subqueries:

```
select t.*, (select array_join(array_agg(t1.v), ', ') from 
  (select v from unnest(t.visitors_today) v
   except
   select v from tbl t2 cross join unnest(t2.visitors_today) v 
   where t2.date < t.date) t1),
  (select array_join(array_distinct(array_agg(v)), ', ') 
   from tbl t1 cross join unnest(t1.visitors_today)) v 
   where t1.date <= t.date)
from tbl t
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/j7J-XPbA) (Demo of query above in Postgres).

Comment: this is great, I am just having trouble and errors with resolving "v" in each subquery in presto

Comment: @theOtherOne Can you post the specific error message?

Comment: I modified the query by removing a parenthesis which was not supposed to be there and casting the array because i kept getting error "INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT) Cannot unnest type: varchar"  After fixing those things, I have this query which results in error: "line 52:17: Column 'v' cannot be resolved"

Comment: step 1 remove this parenthesis:

CAST(JSON_PARSE(t1.visitors_today) AS ARRAY(VARCHAR))
            )
            -- )

Comment: step 2 parse each unnest varchar to satisfy second error like this:
CAST(JSON_PARSE(t2.visitors_today) AS ARRAY(VARCHAR))

Answer (score 1):

Beginning from normalized table, you can aggregate on a ranking value on visitors over dates (first time visit corresponds to ranking = 1), then use a window function on new visitors field to get your increasing visitors.

If you want strings ([fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iRziE65kvGFKeEp8nuUQbj/0)):

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Visitors_Today ORDER BY Date_) AS rn
    FROM tab
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT Date_, 
           STRING_AGG(Visitors_Today, ', ') AS Visitors_Today,
           STRING_AGG(Visitors_Today, ', ') FILTER (WHERE rn = 1) AS New_Visitors
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY Date_
)
SELECT *, 
       STRING_AGG(New_Visitors, ', ') OVER(ORDER BY Date_) AS All_Visitors_To_Date
FROM cte2
```

If you want arrays ([fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iRziE65kvGFKeEp8nuUQbj/1)):

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Visitors_Today ORDER BY Date_) AS rn
    FROM tab
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT Date_, 
           ARRAY_AGG(Visitors_Today) AS Visitors_Today,
           ARRAY_AGG(Visitors_Today) FILTER (WHERE rn = 1) AS New_Visitors
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY Date_
)
SELECT DISTINCT Date_, Visitors_Today, New_Visitors, ARRAY_AGG(elements) OVER(ORDER BY Date_) AS All_Visitors_To_Date
FROM cte2, UNNEST(New_Visitors) AS elements
ORDER BY Date_
```

Comment: this worked!  I just had to switch the "as elements" to "as t(elements)   Thank you so much!

Comment: One question, is the baseline being calculated by grabbing every single field in the table?  Or is it referencing the previous baseline and adding new visitors?  Can the query be modified to be retention proof?  As long as the last entry exists, the new calculations will continue to be valid?

Comment: What do you mean by "baseline" and "retention proof"? Let's say that at the moment, given any data in the format you shared, this algorithm should give you the output you need. Can you craft an example for this case you're referencing? [Use https://www.db-fiddle.com if that makes you comfortable.]

Comment: if this table's data was stored up to 10 entries only.  so when the 11th entry comes in, the first entry is removed.  Only ever having 10 entries stored.  Does your queries calculation of the "all_visitors_to_date" use the previous entry or does it take from the entire table.  If it did that, then the table would be compromised when old entries are deleted

Comment: Calculation of the "all_visitors_to_date" goes from "New_Visitors", field which contains every visitor only once among all the records (works on the whole table). If you get to delete a user, and you want that user to not appear in the "*New_Visitors*" anymore, you'd need to take care of that with a trigger to keep your representation of the data consistent. This query just works on your current representation of the whole table.

Comment: If you use this query as a view, and you call it in different times, you can get different representations according to how your data has changed in time, including added users, removed ones, anything really.

Comment: if I delete a user I want to keep the user actually. If old rows are deleted, the most current rows keep the same data. Meaning if I start with 10 rows stored, with the last running total being "1,2,3,4,5" and then I delete the first 9 rows. My next calculation would be based off that last stored row, so my running total would still be adding to the "1,2,3,4,5" that was previously stored.

Comment: Running a query (for instance a `SELECT` statement) is a static process, not a dynamic one. If you run a query once, it works on the data you have. If you change your data and run the query again, the query will always use the data you currently have - the updated one now. If you want to keep the original data and update it, you need to store the output of your original `SELECT` statement inside a table, and update the table when you need it, either manually or with an after-insert trigger.

Comment: I am trying to have each new row be dependent on the previous row.  At the beginning the row checks if there is a previous row, if not, it sets default values, if there is a previous row, it will use that row's "visitor's to date" to calculate new visitors